# Samsung stock rom has 2 vbmeta image(s) but Heimdall only shows one partition for vbmeta

Tags: samsung, stock-rom

I'm trying to flash stock firmware back to a Samsung Galaxy A51 (SM-A515F), when extracting the rom files and decrypting them from their lz4 formats, I noticed there were 2 vbmeta images (not to be confused with vbmeta_samsung, they're both named "vbmeta.img"), one was at the BL while the other was at the AP, when flashing from Odin3, I noticed that it flashed "vbmeta.img" 2 times, on Heimdall however there was only a single vbmeta partition option available instead of 2, printing the PIT also shows theres only 1 vbmeta partition, how do I flash both vbmeta image(s) to the device using Heimdall? I do not want to use a Windows vm just to get Odin working there.

AGAIN, NOT to be confused with "VBMETA_SAMSUNG", I am talking about "VBMETA"

Comment: are that files different?

Comment: Hey did you get any answer?

Comment: No, however it turns out Heimdall doesn't support newer Samsung devices, I no longer need to flash my A51 as I was forced to make a Windows VM to use Odin anyways.